# How to hide unread SMS notification?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, read-unread

I'm writing application which handles SMS's and as I plan it should replace stock/default application.

I'm intercepting `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast fired by incoming SMS and publishing my own notification and then calling `abortBroadcast()`, so in the end there is no notification for incoming new messages which leads to default/stock app.

But the problem is in fact that when user doesn't read for a long enough time (smth like several minutes) incoming SMS stock/default app aroses another broadcast - I suspect just checking that there's unread sms. So user sees 2 notifications: one from default/stock messaging app and another one from mines, which is messing.

I can't find which broadcast fired when there's unread sms?

Any ideas, hints?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the priority of your receiver this way, so you know that it has the top priority and will execute the `onReceive()` method:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" android:priority="999">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Sorry, you ought to carefully read my question first. I already have receiver which handles incoming SMS's - I'm talking about a bit different thing